# How to make Comments in iFrame Tab on my Fan Page as Page not as user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I have a Page (Public Profile) with 10000 likes, I created a Tabs (as iFrame Apps) with Comments Plugin - now I cant comment there as a Page (Switch to User profile message appears) but need to answer as Page (Company). Similarly I cant delete comment there...

Have any ideas?

RK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried switching to the page (Account Menu -> Use Facebook as a Page)?  If this doesn't work, I usually create a company fake account user with the company name as the users first and last name and make them an admin to answer these requests.

Comment: @OffBySome... Yeah Fake Profile should work to answer, but it's difficult to create one with same as company name (FB detects that it's not a name and declines it) - also even Application Admins cant delete others' Comments from that application...